# AngularJS: Add a loader element to top of DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

Been trying to find out how to do this the best way but haven't found any answers, don't know if I suck at searching or no-one has asked the question. Probably the first one, but anyway.

I'm wondering what the best way is to add an element to the top of the DOM (so that it is on top of everything else) in AngularJS?

My solution to this problem now is to show a modal with the loading spinner in it but I think this is an ugly solution as it shouldn't be that hard to add my own div-element to the DOM that are showing the spinner.

This is the code I have in my modal right now:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
</div>
```

So you can understand why I think it's unnecessary and ugly to have it in a modal. I've been reading about directives but not really sure how it would look like and how I would show it where I want it to be shown.

Comment: You would need to play around with absolute/fixed positioning with z-index. Do you have a demo..?

Comment: take a look at [angular loading bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, in order to work with DOM, you need a directive. And to control loader, you need a service. [Here is a very simple demo for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/iZneZ67GqcLMDDIuQ1bq?p=preview). The principle is: directive watches for state change in service and draws "loader" if service says that loader shoud be presented:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="Demo">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.22" data-semver="1.2.22" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="LoaderController as ctrl">
    <div data-loader class="loader" data-ng-class="{'visible':Loader.visible}"></div>
    <button data-ng-click="ctrl.show(true)">Loader</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('Demo', []);

  angular.module('Demo').directive('loader', [function(){
    return {
      'restrict' : 'A',
      'controller' : ['$scope', 'Loader', function($scope, Loader){
        $scope.Loader = Loader;
      }]
    }
  }]);

  angular.module('Demo').factory('Loader', [function(){
    var instance = {}

    instance.show = function(on){
      instance.visible = on;
    }

    return instance;
  }]);

  angular.module('Demo').controller('LoaderController', ['$timeout', 'Loader', function($timeout, Loader){
    this.show = function(){
      Loader.show(true);
      $timeout(function(){
        Loader.show(false);
      }, 5000)
    }
  }]);
})();
```

**style.css**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loader {
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}

.loader.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just created something just like this for a project of mine. You can make a div and set the size to 100% of the screen. Set some variable on it so that it shows only when the data is loading.

I used the following CSS for mine:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    z-index:10000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Its important to make a large z-index so that it shows on top of everything, and I used a semi-transparent overlay. You can style however you'd like.

And html like the following:

```
<div id="overlay" data-loading>
        <i class="icon-spinner icon-do-spin" ></i>
</div>
```

FYI - 'icon-do-spin' is a cool class provided by FontAwesome to animate the spinner icon that you are using, and 'data-loading' is a directive I used to check for when all http pending requests are completed. You could just use something like ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if to show or hide the loading div.

Comment: I accepted @madhead's answer but I ended up using parts of your CSS as well so thank you also =)